# AJAX SQL JSON Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

My AJAX seems like not working. It should load patient details into a dropwdown.

this is my ajax code:

```
function PopulatePatient()
{
        $("#PatientDropDown").empty();
        $("#PatientDropDown").append("<option>Loading.....</option>");

        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"../listener/populatePatientName.php",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                        $("#PatientDropDown").empty();
                        $("#PatientDropDown").append("<option value=''>-Select Patient-</option>");

                $.each(data,function(i,item)
                {
                    $("#PatientDropDown").append('<option value="'+ data[i].patientUserId +'">'+ data[i].patientFirstName +'</option>');

                });

        },

        complete: function()
        {

        }

        });
}
```

This is my PHP Code (populatePatientName.php):

```
<?php

include '../core/init.php';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT patientUserId,patientFirstName FROM patientdetails");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
{
  $data=array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
$data[]=array
(
  'patientUserId' => $row['patientUserId']
  'patientFirstName' => $row['patientFirstName']
);
}
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
}

 ?>
```

This is my HTML Code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="PatientDropDown">
</select>
```

This code works in my friend PC. My database and query are running well. Table contained data.

My code stop at this point :
    $("#PatientDropDown").append("Loading.....");

It does not enter ajax. Any solution?

Comment: Are you getting any error on browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I forgot the comma,

```
<?php

include '../core/init.php';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT patientUserId,patientFirstName FROM patientdetails");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
{
  $data=array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
$data[]=array
(
  'patientUserId' => $row['patientUserId'],
  'patientFirstName' => $row['patientFirstName']
);
}
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

?>

```
$data[]=array
    (
      'patientUserId' => $row['patientUserId'],
      'patientFirstName' => $row['patientFirstName']
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line before `$.each()` function in ajax success

```
data= JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "GET" instead of "POST" into your ajax type.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is absolutely fine, but you do not have any event which will trigger `PopulatePatient()` function. Run the function to get data. Use `console.log(data)` to check whether your php is sending data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to populatePatientName.php using web browser, it should return JSON data

Comment: Yes it does:

[{"patientUserId":"10001","patientFirstName":"Mohamad Shahiran"},{"patientUserId":"10002","patientFirstName":"Mohamad Shahiran"},{"patientUserId":"10003","patientFirstName":"Mohamad Shakir"}]

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:
- It is included jquery in head tag like this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

- To populate try using a button like:

```
<input type="button" onClick="populatePatient()" />
```